# install smcroute in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, software-installation, multicast

How do I install smcroute in Ubuntu 16.04? If I try to install using apt-get, I am not finding the commands "smcrouted" and "smcroutectl" in bash. Also, the GitHub page asks to configure the kernel to enable multicasting

```
CONFIG_IP_MROUTE=y
CONFIG_IP_PIMSM_V1=y
CONFIG_IP_PIMSM_V2=y
```

Where do I find those configs and how do I hot configure them using echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to reconfigure your kernel on Ubuntu.  Their kernels come with everything you need enabled.

Second, the version of SMCRoute in Ubuntu 16.04 does not have `smcrouted` and `smcroutectl`, the base package is too old.  Instead it comes with the `smcroute` daemon in `/usr/sbin/smcroute`.

The man page installed on your system, and any files in `/usr/share/doc/smcroute`, is more accurate information for your version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `smcroute` package from [ubuntu disco](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/smcroute) which provide `smcroutectl` and `smcrouted` ([list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/smcroute/filelist)).

Add `disco universe` to your sources.list:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

past the following line:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
```

Create a preferences file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/smcroute.pref
```

with the following content:

```
Package: smcroute
Pin: release n=disco
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Configuring apt-conf:

```
echo 'APT::Default-Release "xenial";' |  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

Install `smcroute` from Ubuntu Disco:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge smcroute
sudo apt install -t disco smcroute
```

The manpage is updated with the `smcroutectl` and the `smcrouted` commands.

see [`man smcroute`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/smcroute/smcroute.8.en.html) on debian.